# Specify Dynamic keys in openapi yaml

Tags: openapi

I want to create a response structure like this where either fieldProfile (profile type) or summaryProfile is optional. i.e outer key is dynamic and optional

```
{
    "fieldProfile": [
        "metric1",
        "metric2",
        "metric3"
    ],
    "summaryProfile": [
        "metric1",
        "metric2",
        "metric3"
    ]
}
```

Or

```
{
    "fieldProfile": [
        "metric1",
        "metric2",
        "metric3"
    ]
} // Here Summary Profile is removed, similarly we can have a response of summaryProfile or have both in response
```

I am creating the response schema like this, but here I want the metricType (fieldProfile/summaryProfile) to be the key for metrics (metric list).

```
ProfileMetrics:
  description: List of metrics available in Field Profile
  type: object
  required:
    - metricType
    - metrics
  properties:
    metrics:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        required:
          - metricName
        properties:
          metricName:
            type: string
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema can be defined as follows:

```yaml
MySchema:
  type: object
  properties:
    fieldProfile:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
    summaryProfile:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string

  # At least fieldProfile or summaryProfile (or both) must be present
  minProperties: 1
```

Instead of `minProperties: 1`, you can use this `anyOf` + `required` construct, it will achieve the same effect in this example:

```yaml
  anyOf:
    - required: [fieldProfile]
    - required: [summaryProfile]
```